# HERE Map's platform.getPlacesService() API is not returning phone number

Tags: javascript, here-api

Can anyone suggest which **API** of HERE MAP's returns place details along with **phone number** (Just like Google map : places.PlacesService()/textSearch()) ?

I am using HERE maps **getPlacesService()** to search any user input and this API is not returning a phone number.

**For Sample Code  :** https://developer.here.com/apiexplorer-v2-sample-data/template-web-two-box/examples/search-for-places/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
// Assumption: the platform is instantiated
var places = platform.getPlacesService()
var entryPoint = H.service.PlacesService.EntryPoint;

places.request(entryPoint.SEARCH, { 'at': '52.5044,13.3909', 'q': 'pizza'}, function(resp) {
 console.log(resp);
}, function(resp) {
 console.log('ERROR: '+resp);
});

NOTE : you can pass 'at' and 'q' dynamically
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/places.html#refining-search-results__search-results-additional-details) for requesting more details on a specific place.

```
...
var explore = new H.places.Explore(platform.getPlacesService());

explore.request(params, headers, onResult, onError);

function onResult(data) {
  // Get the details of the first item (place) from the results:
  data.results.items[0].follow(onFetchPlaceDetails, onError);
}

// Define a callback to process a successful response to the
// request for place details:
function onFetchPlaceDetails(data) {
  placeDetails = data;
}
...
```

From here, you can access the `phone` array of the [`contacts` Object](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/object-contacts.html) contained in the [Places REST response](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/media-type-place.html) (`placeDetails` in the above snippet).

Note that as the HERE Places JS API is a very thin wrapper on the REST API, the names of Object properties match the REST API / JSON names.

You can explore the [Place Details Response Here](https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/8409q8zn-ef4e19f83b2e478d8e5ba871dbe7850b;context=Zmxvdy1pZD03ZDRmMDQzZS1hOTk4LTUyNGQtYjk5Yy03MzcxODFmNTUxZTFfMTUwNzA1MjI0MTQ1MF81MDc0Xzg3ODMmcmFuaz0w?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

Comment: Thank you AnsrewJC for helpful answer,  i used below posted answer to get place details along with contact info.